# DisplayForModel() not displaying complex objects + MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the below model:

```
public class Car
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Colour { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
}
public class Category
{
    public int CatId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I am returning the model to view as below:

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var car = new Car { Id = 1, Colour = "Black", Category = new Category { CatId = 2, Name = "Audi" } };

        return View(car);
    }
```

My view is :

```
@model MvcApplication6.Models.Car

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Car";
 }

@Html.DisplayForModel()
```

This is not displaying the Category.
I have and found this is a bug in MVC, and as a workaround I need to override Object.ascx displaytemplate.

So I have added, object.cshtml in Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/ folder, the code is below.

```
@functions{
public bool ShouldShow(ModelMetadata metadata)
{
    //return number % 2 == 0 ? true : false;

    return metadata.ShowForDisplay
       && metadata.ModelType != typeof(System.Data.EntityState)
       && !metadata.IsComplexType
       && !ViewData.TemplateInfo.Visited(metadata);
}
}

@if (Model == null) {
@(ViewData.ModelMetadata.NullDisplayText)
} else if (ViewData.TemplateInfo.TemplateDepth > 1) {
@(ViewData.ModelMetadata.SimpleDisplayText)
} else {
foreach (var prop in ViewData.ModelMetadata.Properties.Where(pm => ShouldShow(pm))) {
    if (prop.HideSurroundingHtml) {
        @(Html.Display(prop.PropertyName))
    } else {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(prop.GetDisplayName())) {
            <div class="display-label">@(prop.GetDisplayName())</div>
        }
        <div class="display-field">@(Html.Display(prop.PropertyName))</div>
        }
    }
}
```

however still the catogery is not getting displayed, can somebody advsie?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hm, i made everything like you and got code for template from here: http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-3-default-templates.html

**HomeController.cs**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Home/
        public class Car
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Colour { get; set; }
            public Category Category { get; set; }
        }

        public class Category
        {
            public int CatId { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
        }

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var car = new Car { Id = 1, Colour = "Black", Category = new Category { CatId = 2, Name = "Audi" } };

            return View(car);
        }
    }
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
@model MvcApplication1.Controllers.HomeController.Car

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Car";
}

@Html.DisplayForModel()
```

**Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/Object.ascx**

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl" %>
<% if (Model == null) { %>
    <%= ViewData.ModelMetadata.NullDisplayText %>
<% }
   else if (ViewData.TemplateInfo.TemplateDepth > 1) { %>
    <%= ViewData.ModelMetadata.SimpleDisplayText %>
<% }
   else { %>
    <% foreach (var prop in ViewData.ModelMetadata.Properties.Where(pm => pm.ShowForDisplay
                         && !ViewData.TemplateInfo.Visited(pm))) { %>
        <% if (prop.HideSurroundingHtml) { %>
            <%= Html.Display(prop.PropertyName) %>
        <% }
           else { %>
            <% if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(prop.GetDisplayName())) { %>
                <div class="display-label"><%= prop.GetDisplayName() %></div>
            <% } %>
            <div class="display-field"><%= Html.Display(prop.PropertyName) %></div>
        <% } %>
    <% } %>
<% } %>
```

And i have this result:

[image]

**Edit:**

By the way, if you remove this code from DisplayTemplate:

```
if (ViewData.TemplateInfo.TemplateDepth > 1) { %>
    <%= ViewData.ModelMetadata.SimpleDisplayText %>
<% }
```

You could see next result:

[image]

That's happen, because when display template started to display `Category Category` property, `TemplateDepth` gone to be 2 and you just see identity property, not full object.